# Can't view/load certain documents in Chrome - ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION

Tags: node.js, http, browser, server, backend

I consistently encounter the ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION error when fetching the URL. The issue appears to be in the response header, which is as follows:

```
inline; filename="car.glb", inline; name="car.glb"; filename="car.glb"
```

It should not return ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION